# POST 500 (Internal Server Error) - Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I already checked out similar questions but I can't find what's the problem with my code, what I'm trying to do, is create products, so what my code is supposedly to do is to make an ajax call for every product, even if it wasn't modified. But sometimes it works, and sometimes it throws the error.

JS

```
for (var i = 0; i < $('.pds').length; i++) {
    var pds_items = $('.pds').length;
    var pds_counter = 0;
    var pds = $(".pds").eq(i);    

    var data = new FormData();    
    $(pds).append( "<input name='position' type='hidden'/>" );
    $(pds).append( "<input name='titulo' type='hidden'/>" );
    $(pds).append( "<input name='descripcion' type='hidden'/>" );
    $(pds).append( "<input name='pds_id' type='hidden'/>" );
    data.append("titulo", pds.find("input[name=titulo]").val());
    data.append("descripcion", pds.find("input[name=descripcion]").val());
    data.append("position", i);
    data.append("pds_id", pds.attr("id"));
    //alert(pds.attr("id"));

    if (pds.find("input[name=pdsimg]").get(0).files.length != 0) {

    $(pds).append( "<input name='img_type' type='hidden'/>" );
    $(pds).append( "<input name='img_status' type='hidden'/>" );
    data.append('img_type', 'pds');
    data.append('img_status', "1");      
    data.append('tmp_img', pds.find("input[name=pdsimg]").prop('files')[0]);

    } else { 

      $(pds).append( "<input name='img_status' type='hidden'/>" );    
      data.append('img_status', "0");   

    }        

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',               
            processData: false, // important
            contentType: false, // important
            data: data,
            url: "update_pds.php",

              success: function(data) {
                pds_counter++;                
                if (pds_counter == pds_items) {                 
                  pds_ready = 1;
                  allReady();
                }
              },
              error: function(jqXHR, status, error) { 
              console.log(jqXHR); 
              console.log(status); 
              console.log(error);
              //alert("Hubo un problema");
              //location.reload();
              //console.log("Error al actualizar");
              } 
          });  
  }
```

PHP

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'balaboxc_javier', '*****', 'balaboxc_xauty');

session_start();
    if ( isset($_SESSION['XautySV'])!="" ) {
    $user_id = $_SESSION['XautySV'];
    }

$titulo = $_POST["titulo"];
$descripcion = $_POST["descripcion"];
$pds_id = $_POST["pds_id"];
$titulo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$titulo);
$descripcion = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$descripcion);
$position = $_POST["position"];

$img_type = $_POST["img_type"];
$img_status = $_POST["img_status"];
$filetmp = $_FILES["tmp_img"]["tmp_name"];
$filename = $_FILES["tmp_img"]["name"];
$filename = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$filename);
$filetype = $_FILES["tmp_img"]["type"];
$filepath = "bgs/".$filename;
$filepath = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $filepath);

if ($titulo == "" && $descripcion == "" && $filename == "") {
    // El producto está vacío, por lo tanto no se hace nada         
    $check = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `pds_svs` WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id' AND `id` = '$pds_id'") or exit(mysqli_error());
    if(mysqli_num_rows($check)){
        //$sql = "UPDATE pds_svs SET title=' ', description=' ' WHERE position='$position' AND user_id='$user_id';"     
        $sql = "DELETE FROM pds_svs WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND id = '$pds_id';";
        $conn->multi_query($sql);
        //mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM `pds_svs` WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id' AND `position` = '$position'");
    }
    echo "1";
} else {

$check = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `pds_svs` WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id' AND `id` = '$pds_id'") or exit(mysqli_error());

if(mysqli_num_rows($check)){

    //Subir a base de datos
    $sql = "UPDATE pds_svs SET title='$titulo', description='$descripcion' WHERE id='$pds_id' AND user_id='$user_id';";

    if ($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
        if ($img_status == 1) {

            if (move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath)) {

                //Subir a base de datos
                    $sql = "UPDATE pds_svs SET img_url='$filepath' WHERE user_id='$user_id' AND id='$pds_id';";             

                    if ($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
                        echo "1";
                    } else {
                        echo "0";       
                    }
                //Fin Subir a base de datos

            }
        }
        //echo "1";
    } else {
        echo "0";       
    }
    //Subir a base de datos

} else {    

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT MAX(position) FROM pds_svs WHERE user_id = '$user_id'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result); 
    if ($position != 0) {
        $position = $row[0]; 
        $position++;
    }

    //Subir a base de datos
    $sql = "INSERT INTO pds_svs (user_id, title, description, position) VALUES ('$user_id', '$titulo', '$descripcion', '$position');";
    if ($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {

        if ($img_status == 1) {

            if (move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath)) {               

                //Subir a base de datos
                    $sql = "UPDATE pds_svs SET img_url='$filepath' WHERE user_id='$user_id' AND position='$position';";             

                    if ($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
                        echo "1";
                    } else {
                        echo "0";       
                    }
                //Fin Subir a base de datos

            }
        }

        //echo "1";
    } else {
        echo "0"; 
    }   
    //Fin Subir a base de datos

}

} // Esta llave cierra la sentencia que evalua si el producto tiene información o no

?>
```

Comment: 500 status code == check your error logs

Comment: @PatrickQ it says is internal server error, is that what you mean? O where can I exactly check it inside my logs?

Comment: are you using Localhost?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento No

Comment: @PatrickQ I checked cPanel logs and it says this:
 Cannot allocate memory: [client 189.235.80.177:65149] couldn't create child process:

Comment: Looks like you're just plain running out of memory.  Could be dependent upon how large the file is that you're uploading.

Comment: @PatrickQ It happens also when I only upload text, I mean without any large file or picture

Comment: `$.ajax` is within a for loop. how many requests are actually happening? You may be hitting a thread limit for FPM (or other equivalent)

Comment: @apokryfos It's a variable number, user creates X number of products, and for each product an Ajax call will be executed